# Do new iPhones (iOS 13) support NFC in peer-to-peer mode?

Tags: iphone, ios, nfc

Yesterday I did quite a googling about iPhone and NFC. Learned cool things like iOS 13 adding support for tag writing and background tag reading. And that there are 3 modes in NFC (read/write; peer-to-peer; card emulation).

All I wanted (before googling all of this) was simply to share an URL *using NFC* and I failed at that.

Since tag writing is now supported I thought that that was possible, but couldn’t find anything.

With iOS 13, does anyone know if it’s possible to exchange information (peer-to-peer mode) like an URL using NFC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

Peer-to-Peer mode (like sharing contacts, URLs or pictures) is currently not on the road map.

A quick look at the [Apple developer site](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc#overview) and we can confirm this.  The only function Core NFC supports (at the time of this writing), is tag reading and writing.

> Detect NFC tags, read messages that contain NDEF data, and save data
>   to writable tags.

A Computerworld article, [WWDC: Apple’s NFC plan is a big developer opportunity](https://www.computerworld.com/article/3276649/wwdc-apple-s-nfc-plan-is-a-big-developer-opportunity.html), seems to confirm this.  The focus appears to be reading/writing tags that enhance "guest experience" like that of payments, security, loyalty cards, and even drivers licenses and passports.  There's no mention of "convenience" like that of sharing digital assets between users.