# Can iOS NFC reader display notes?

Tags: ios, nfc

Can the native iOS NFC reader be used for simple notes?
I can program all tags with links, actions etc. As soon I store a simple text the native reader just won't read the tag.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense.  The NFC reader can only [read/write RFID tags](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/379533/119271).  What you do after that is up to your application.  This also sounds like a development question.  Maybe [so]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - you could embed the notes in a database and trigger display from the encoding on the tag.

If you’re writing specific content into an NFC and asking how the OS handles arbitrary items, we might need a substantial edit to the question and possibly move it to a different site, but many apps do this.

Apple has code ready to run, frameworks, WWDC videos and more on how the capabilities and hardware and software work together.

- https://developer.apple.com/wwdc20/10140